# Open a new Page on NodeJS Server with Javascript and add some stuff?

Tags: javascript, html, lit-element

I code a webapp and now i want to open a new Window using JS and inserting some code in the new Window. This is the code I already tried, but with no success:

```
    var win = window.open("TimeTableView.html", "_blank");
    var pTag = win.document.createElement('p');
    pTag.appendChild(win.document.createTextNode('test'));
    win.document.body.innerHTML.appendChild(pTag);
    win.focus();
```

But the

didn't append on the window's body. What can I do to append Tags on the new window?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `innerHTML` is a string property not the dom element, ie `document.body.appendChild`

Comment: Thanks for your response! In Chrome, Opera, etc. doesn't work it at all :/

Comment: Check the console for errors, F12 on most browsers console tab

Comment: There are no errors :(